# how do i connect event listener to textarea element?

Tags: javascript

I really struggling with this.
I need to basically make it so whatever is written in a newly created textbox is stored in local storage.

```
// TODO: Q1(c)(iii)
 // Make an event listener to save text when it changes:
 // ...get the textarea element's current value
 // ...make a text item using the value
 // ...store the item in local storage using the given key
 // Connect the event listener to the textarea element
 var item, data, key;
 var textareaElement = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
   textareaElement.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    var myText = document.getElementById("textareaElement").value;
    localStorage.setItem("text", myText);
    item = makeItem ("text", myText); 
 });

-- HTML --

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Erehwon Diary ds22368</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Stephen Rice" />
    <!-- Set viewport to ensure this page scales correctly on mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tma03.css" />
    <!-- Set demo data -->
    <script src="tma03-demo.js"></script>
    <!-- Start TMA03 application -->
    <script src="tma03.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Erehwon Diary ds22368</h1>
    <main>
      <section id="text" class="button">
        <button type="button">Add entry</button>
      </section>
      <section id="image" class="button">
        <button type="button">Add photo</button>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

The questions for each line are the comments above, and below them is what I've tried so far.

Comment: Please post your html too?

Comment: ah yes edited thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var item, data, key;
var textareaElement = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
document.body.appendChild(textareaElement); //Add the element to the document
textareaElement.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var mytext = textareaElement.value; //You already have the element as a variable
  localStorage.setItem("text", myText);
  item = makeItem("text", myText); 
});

function makeItem() { //Don't forget to define makeItem
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an input like this in your HTML

```
 <textarea id=‘textarea’ onchange=‘save()’ />
```

In JS:

```
const textarea = document.querySelector(‘#textarea’)
function save() { 
  localStorage.setItem("text", textarea.value);
 }
```